# Ubuntu - Create a link to a specified directory so I can easily change to that directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link, alias

Is it possible to create a symlink to a directory, like /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/MyWar that I can access from everywhere?  I want to be able to say `cd myapp` from anywhere in the directory tree and go to that directory.  Is it only possible in the directory where I create the symlink?

Do I have to update my ~/.bashrc file to include an alias like: `alias myapp="cd /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/MyWar"` and then just type `myapp` from anywhere?  What is the best way to handle this situation so I don't always have to type in the long directory?  I also want to be able to use that parameter in say a copy command, so the alias wouldn't help in that situation.  Hopefully I can do something similar where ~ maps to the home directory in any command.

Answer (score 5):

If you put a link in your home directory you can do

```
$ cd ~/myapp
```

It means typing two extra characters, but it'll work.

Or you could use environment variables and do

```
$ cd $MYAPP
```

Comment: +1 Setting the environment variable is the standard way to so this.
Adding export MYWAR="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/MyWar" to your .bashrc file will allow you to do cd $MYWAR from anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the CDPATH environment variable to .:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps in your .[bash_]profile and you are set. Wherever you are, "cd myWar" will work as you expect it to do.

Comment: +1 for the KISS approach instead of futzing with symlinks. For reference, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: You know, I've been using various unix system for 20 years and didn't know this. Happen to know what shell introduced it?

Comment: I have been using it since more than 20 years but it is true CDPATH isn't at all a well know shell feature.
As far as I know, it appeared in System V release 1 bourne shell (1983).

Answer (score 3):

I keep a list of links in a folder in my home directory so that I can easily do:

```
cd ~/bm/myapp
```

Those "bookmarks" are generated and synchronized with the `.gtk-bookmarks` file (used by Nautilus and other GUI file managers) through the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/file:\/\/\(.*\)/\1/' $HOME/.gtk-bookmarks | while read dir name
do
 ln -s $dir $HOME/bm/$name
done
```

Comment: Pretty cool stuff, though I'd redo that script in Ruby. Man are "real" shell scripts ugly.

Comment: I rewrote the proposed shell script... maybe now is more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

`ln -s /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/MyWar ~/myapp` and then you can do `cd ~/myapp` etc. the simlink can be used for most purposes exactly as if it were the actual directory (ie. cd will work, cp or mv will put a file in the directory rather than replacing the symlink with the file etc.).

Comment: Why `ln -s` as opposed to just `ln` (hard link)?

Comment: @Yar, you can't hard-link directories