# CDPATH in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash

The accepted answer of this question [Fast Ways of Cd'ing on *nix?](https://superuser.com/questions/141825/fast-ways-of-cding-on-nix)    mentions bash having CDPATH

is there an equivalent in windows?

so from any directory e.g.  c:\windows>
I could do c:\windows>cd compbar*    and it'd take me to m:\a\b\c\d\e\compbar

what if there are many compbar directories? well, the CDPATH solution is one solution, I suppose you order them it'd search through the CDPATH environment variable and choose the first.

I'd like that for windows.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx

Comment: @Moab Can you be more specific about what method within powershell?

Comment: It was a suggestion to investigate, not up on powershell myself, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "Cd Deluxe" for a greatly improved "change directory" command: http://www.plan10.com/cdd/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a doskey macro that uses cdpath variable when changing directories.

```
cd=echo off&set _=$*\$tset _=%_:"=%&set _o=%CD%&set _c=%_:.=..\%$tset_=%_:/=\%$tif "%_:~0,3%" equ "..." set _=..\%_c:~5%$tif "%_%" equ "-\" set _=%OLDPWD%$tfor %V in (" ";"%CDPATH:;=\";"%\") do if defined _c chdir /d "%~V%_%" 2>nul&&set _c=&&set OLDPWD=%_o%$tif defined _c echo Directory "%_:~0,-1%" not found$tfor %V in ("%CD:\=" "%") do if "%~V" neq "" set _=%~V$ttitle %_% - %CD%&set _=&set _c=&set _o=&echo on
```

Here is my cdpath:

> CDPATH=.\;..\;c:\;C:\Program Files\;C:\work

In the work directory is a directory called `perlscripts`.

You can type `cd perls*`
and you will change directory to `C:\work\perlscripts`

---

> - **cd -**     change directory to previous directory
> - **cd**       change to root directory
> - **cd ..**     move up one directory
> - **cd ...**    move up two directories
> - **cd ....**   move up three directories

...and so on.

Here is a doskey macro to view `cdpath`

```
cdpath=set _a=echo.^&echo.CDPATH = %cdpath:;=^&echo.%$t%_a%$tset _a=

CDPATH = .\
         ..\
         c:\
         C:\Program Files\
         C:\work
```

Comment: Ron, please [edit] and fix your formatting if you can. You need to indent code by 4 spaces. Thank you!